# `gulp-connect` virtual folder

Tags: gulp, gulp-connect

Is it possible to get `gulp-connect` to add a non-existent folder into a URL?

To elaborate:

My project is in `/Sites/mySite`, in this folder I have a `gulpfile.js` and I `cd` into this folder, run `gulp` and get a http server on: `http://localhost:8080/`.

I would like to still be able to `cd` into `/Sites/mySite` run `gulp` but have the url for this content accessible from `http://localhost:8080/igloo`.

This feels like some sort of middleware but I cannot get my head around connect/gulp-connect.

Comment: Do I need to elaborate?

Comment: Please.. elaborate your question. I am unable to get what query you are facing

Comment: I want to create a sub folder in the url which does not exist in the file system. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a similar setup. The root of my app is at `dist/`, but I also need access to `node_modules/` for my source maps:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/st

```
var st = require('st')

...

gulp.task('server', function() {
  connect.server({
    root: 'dist/',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3000,
    livereload: {
      port: 35929
    },
    middleware: function (connect, opt) {
      return [
        st({ path: 'node_modules', url: '/node_modules' })
      ];
    }
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use symlink.

Let say your app is in /Sites/mySite/app folder and you run server like this:

```
gulp.task('server', function () {
  connect.server({
    root: './app'
  });
});
```

Now create symlink igloo to ./app and run server like this:

```
var
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  connect = require('gulp-connect');

gulp.task('server', function () {
  connect.server({
    root: '.'
  });
});
```

That’s all. You’ll see your app at http://localhost:8080/igloo .
Feel free to ask more.

Comment: Funnily enough someone at work just suggested this. I can see how that would work but it feels like a dirty solution (it requires manual steps and isn't self-documenting). I have been beginning to look at modrewrite for node -- thoughts?

Comment: you see, unusual, nonstandard ideas demands dirty solutions ))

Comment: Is there no better solution (like middleware -- proxy / static or using modrewrite)?

Comment: I have awarded you the bounty -- thank you for responding :)

Comment: I'm not going to mark this as the answer for now as I want to find a cleaner solution.